# Best way to store common data in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, sharedpreferences

Im new in Android Studio.
When a user login in my app I send to the MainActivity with **putExtra()**:

- name
- lastname
- email
- phone
- IdUser

In a few activities later (3 or 4 activities), I have to use the id of the user, the email, the lastname. 
Now a day, from the Main Activity to the fourth activity I'm sending with **putExtra()** the email, the name, the id, the lastname. But I just need those data in the last activity no in the second and third activities.

There is a best way to solve that?. I think in Shared Preferences, but I don't want to the user can see his user id, or the data that my app is saving.

**What is the best practice for this kind of problem?**

Thanks!

Comment: SharedPreferences are stored in internal storage, so unless your user has a rooted device, they can't read it.

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to take the risk. How everyone do with the user id? the email, etc?

Comment: probably use cryptography for fields you don't want to be visible. Since a user enters his mail why don't you want it to be visible I don't get it.

Comment: There are many ways to solve this. If you want to keep it in memory, you can attach the data to an instance of `android.app.Application` (or any other static field), but this comes with some disadvantages. Alternatively, use intent extras as you already tried. If the data should be persistent, save it using `SharedPreferences`, in the application cache directory or in a file in the application's `data` directory. Neither the user nor other applications can access the data.

Comment: @marduc812 The id i dont want the user see. Is not a good practice the user know his id

Comment: Why does the app need to have a reference to the id? Isn't an authentication token enough? (assuming you could make one)

Comment: @cricket_007 In the last activity the user have to save data in the mysql database, and I have to know his id to persist in the database

Answer (score 0):

You have to use SharedPreference to keep the data accessible to all the Activites in your app 
Also if you are trying to Authenticate your User, Check out Firebase Authentication https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/

Comment: Ok, but when a user have to persist inn the database, for example have to buy a product, I have to insert  IdProduct, nameProduct, user_id,

This use_id is a foreign key, but how can i know which id have the user if I don't pass it between activies to the last activity where I have to persist in the database? Must be save it in the shared preference? What happen if the user change the id open the shared preference?